# docker how to set containers to only use ips within a sepcified range

Tags: docker

In docker how to set so that any containers created have an ip
within a range.

For example I would all containers to be assigned an ip starting 172.20.x.x

on my current instance

I have these interface created as default

docker0 is ip address 172.17.0.1

br0-52fxxx ip adress 172.18.0.1

my containers have ip address starting 172.18.x.x

On the suggestion to use --bip=CIDR, does this not set docker0.
Is docker0 the issue becuase even when in my example my docker0 is 172.17.0.1
my containers are starting 172.18.x.x

I belive I require the br0 interface to be 172.20.0.1 to effect all containers
be allocated ips starting 172.20.x.x

I think the question is how to set the br0 interfaces to 172.20.0.1 automaticaly by docker daemon?

Comment: which version of docker are you using, and one which OS?

Comment: centos 7 - docker 17.03 ce

Comment: I'm pretty sure the containers should be starting on the docker0 interface by default

Answer (score 0):

The [--bip flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/) for the docker daemon allows you to change the CIDR configuration for docker0.

> `--bip=CIDR`: supply a specific IP address and netmask for the docker0 bridge, using standard CIDR notation. For example: 192.168.1.5/24.

For your range this would look like this: `--bip=172.20.0.0/16`